# Keyboard height needed before the textfield delegate is called

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

So I have the following code:

```
 //MARK: - Textfield delegate Methods

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
    {

        // update view based on updates in the constraints
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        //perform animation to grow the dockview
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.dockViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.keyBoardHeight + 60
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

and

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)        
}


func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        keyBoardHeight =  contentInsets.bottom
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is the following. When the user clicks on the textfield, the keyboard should open up, and the View which I made should move up. 
I get the height from the keyboard from the `keyboardWillShow` function that is triggered by a NSNotification.

The problem is the following: when I run the code, the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is being called before the `NSNotification`, making my self.keyBoardHeight value 0 (init value). Is there a way I can call the `NSNotification` part before pressing on the textField?

Comment: you have to use TPKeyboardAvoiding third party Library

Comment: Just give a better initial guess, rather than 0.

Comment: this is link  https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: @Birendra thanks, but there should be a different way to solve this, instead of copying in an entire third party library

Answer (score 0):

Set up a isKeyboardShown flag in your viewController to keep track whether keyboard is shown or not, the height which intersects with your element "myElement" can be captured in fieldMovement property as below

```
    if !isKeyboardShown
            {
                if let info = notification.userInfo
                {
                    if fieldMovement == nil
                    {
                        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
                        var keyboardEndRect = CGRectZero

                        //Get frame of keyboard view object
                        ((info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue)).getValue(&keyboardEndRect)

                        /* Convert the frame from the window's coordinate system to our view's coordinate system */
                        keyboardEndRect = view.convertRect(keyboardEndRect, fromView: window)

                        /* Find out how much of our view is being covered by the keyboard */
                        fieldMovement = CGRectIntersection(myElement.frame, keyboardEndRect).height
                    }

                    //Get animation duration of keyboard
                    var animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0
                    (info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).getValue(&animationDuration)

                    // Move views up by intersected height
                UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration)
                {
                    //animate your objects here
                }
            }
            isKeyboardShown = true
        }
```

Comment: how does this make my NSNotification go off before the textFieldDidBeginEditing?

Comment: You do not need to implement textFieldDidBeginEditing: method the keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide notifications are received from the keyboard not the textField